# CSS Box Model Attribute Ordering Convention

Tags: attributes, conventions, css

If you ever wonder in what order to enter your CSS attributes like `border`, `padding`, `font-family`, etc. Two common approaches seem to be Alphabetical and Box Model. (See: 
[Conventional Order of CSS properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878655))

This not to be confused with selectors (`#id`, `.class`, `:hover`, `tagname`) in which case the order matters very much.

The Alphabetical option does not make much sense to me. For one thing it sticks `padding` and `line-height` in the middle of `width` and `height` or `left` and `top`.

I will post a CW answer with the [list from fordinteractive.com](http://fordinteractive.com/tools/propertyorder/propertyorder.css) which was provided by [jacobangel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878655/conventional-order-of-css-attributes/4878696#4878696).

It is very nice, but it is not complete. There are a few items missing. I hope to find out where the missing ones go like `font-style` and `clip`.

Where should these new ones go in the list? Are there any others that are missing? If there was already a suggestion for the same thing then vote for that comment to show you think it is a good idea. Also there will probably be more that are missing. I hope for this to be a complete list. It would also be a good idea if there was a tool or IDE feature that would sort by this list.

I am posting this because there does not seem to be another page that can be found on Google and [the one I do know of](http://fordinteractive.com/tools/propertyorder/propertyorder.css) is incomplete (not even on Google that I could find). I expect that if new ones are edited in that we will have a complete list that everyone can follow.

Comment: You should clarify what your question is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Box Model Convention copied from http://fordinteractive.com/tools/propertyorder/propertyorder.css.

Additions should be edited in when they are found to be missing from the list. Please comment on where you think that additions and wait for some agreement before adding them to the final list.

```
display: ;
visibility: ;
float: ;
clear: ;

position: ;
top: ;
right: ;
bottom: ;
left: ;
z-index: ;

width: ;
min-width: ;
max-width: ;
height: ;
min-height: ;
max-height: ;
overflow: ;

margin: ;
margin-top: ;
margin-right: ;
margin-bottom: ;
margin-left: ;

padding: ;
padding-top: ;
padding-right: ;
padding-bottom: ;
padding-left: ;

border: ;
border-top: ;
border-right: ;
border-bottom: ;
border-left: ;

border-width: ;
border-top-width: ;
border-right-width: ;
border-bottom-width: ;
border-left-width: ;

border-style: ;
border-top-style: ;
border-right-style: ;
border-bottom-style: ;
border-left-style: ;

border-color: ;
border-top-color: ;
border-right-color: ;
border-bottom-color: ;
border-left-color: ;

outline: ;

list-style: ;

table-layout: ;
caption-side: ;
border-collapse: ;
border-spacing: ;
empty-cells: ;

font: ;
font-family: ;
font-size: ;
line-height: ;
font-weight: ;
text-align: ;
text-indent: ;
text-transform: ;
text-decoration: ;
letter-spacing: ;
word-spacing: ;
white-space: ;
vertical-align: ;
color: ;

background: ;
background-color: ;
background-image: ;
background-repeat: ;
background-position: ;

opacity: ;

cursor: ;

content: ;
quotes: ;
```

- Where should `clip` go?
- Where should `user-select` go? (not supported except by Mozilla with `-moz-user-select` and Chrome with `-webkit-user-select`. IE uses JavaScript `onselectstart`)
- Where should `border-radius` go? (not supported except by Mozilla with `-moz-border-radius` and Chrome with `-webkit-border-radius`)

Please comment if you have a suggestion as to where something should go.

Comment: I think opacity should be placed next to the display/ visibility properties, rather than by itself and almost completely at the bottom. Although opacity will not remove an element from the DOM flow like display will, it serves basically the same function as visibility with the caveat that it can be incrememnted

Comment: I'd also like to suggest that the content property be moved up to the top as well. Since content is only valid on pseudo-elements, and is required in order for them to show, it is essentially a display property. Furthermore, 90%+ of its usage is as an empty string just to make the element show. When content is left off, it can be annoying and difficult to debug as the pseudo-element won't even show in the web isnpector

Comment: Lastly, vertical-align should be placed directly next to display, because it only takes effect if display: inline-block is applied. Properties that are 100% dependent on each other should be ordered next to each other to prevent silly mistakes when one is changed.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to:

- Group the properties with similar functions (like `height` and `width` or `clear` and `float`) because if we change the value of one property, we often change the value of other properties in the group too.
- Order the property groups such that they are in decision sequence. For example `position` before `float`, because if I choose `position: absolute`, `float` will be irrelevant.