# Convention about write css property

Tags: css

I m looking for the best way to write css property code (not class name and organization but inside a css block).
In order to make it more maintainable, efficiency and readable by front-end team but also understandable by back-end team.
For now, i lean on two ways:

[Box model convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938571/css-box-model-attribute-ordering-convention):

```
.class {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 123px;
    margin: 27px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: blue;
    background: red;
}
```

Alphabetical:

```
.class {
    background: red;
    color: blue;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 27px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 123px;
}
```

According to you, what is the best solution and why? this or another method.

Comment: This question I don't think is a good fit for SO because in my view it is opinion based. However, you can have a look at the suggestions mentioned [here](http://codeguide.co/#css-declaration-order).

Comment: This might be better at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow @mdo's order from his code guide, [here](http://codeguide.co/#css-declaration-order). 
I find this really easy to understand and very clear especially with the spaces.

```
.declaration-order {
  /* Positioning */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;

  /* Box-model */
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  /* Typography */
  font: normal 13px "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;

  /* Visual */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 3px;

  /* Misc */
  opacity: 1;
}
```