# What order should you put CSS properties in?

Tags: css, standards

Is there a correct order to put your CSS properties in?  I've never been told to put my properties in a certain order. I guess it's personal preference?

Server side languages have various standards you can code to. Are there standards for CSS?

I tend to do:

```
.element
{
    /* display: */
    /* position:, top:, right:, bottom:, left: */
    /* width:, height: */
    /* margin:, padding: */
    /* color:, font: */
    /* background: */
    /* border:, border:radius: */
    /* z-index: */
}
```

Comment: "Server side languages have various standards you can code to" - for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though there is no standard around it. 
And probably that's how a declarative DSL should be.

The following links might give you an idea on how you can form a standard for your domain

- [Conventional Order of CSS properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878655/conventional-order-of-css-properties)
- [CSS Lisible](http://csslisible.com/en/)
- [CSS Comb](http://csscomb.com/)
- [Order Your CSS Properties](http://css-tricks.com/poll-results-how-do-you-order-your-css-properties/)

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't a correct order to do that, you just do the way you want and try to organize the css properties the best way you can.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, there isn't a specific order. Late properties shadow others, but that's all

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a commonly-used standard (in my experience - ten years writing CSS, freelance at various different companies for the last 6, all in the UK).

I suspect this is because it doesn't matter that much. Assuming you have no duplicate properties, the order doesn't affect how the code works, and although it's a bit easier to read when property order is consistent, it's obviously easier when *writing* to go with whatever order your brain comes up with.

CSS Tricks did [a poll on CSS property order](http://css-tricks.com/poll-results-how-do-you-order-your-css-properties/) last year. The most popular answer was "grouped by type" (closely followed closely by "randomly", i.e. no particular order), although "type" doesn't seem to be defined specifically.

[Google's CSS Style Guide decided on alphabetical order for properties](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml#Declaration_Order).